# What size wire for a 60A sub-panel at 185 feet?

Tags: electrical, wiring, subpanel

I have a 200 amp panel in my house. I want to run electric 185 feet buried and put in 60 amp sub panel in garage. I'm hoping this will give me 4 15 amp breakers in garage. What size wire do I need?

Comment: Note that you don't add the branch breakers to arrive at the main breaker capacity. Most main panels, for example, would greatly exceed the main breaker. It's more about how many circuits you need in most cases. Even if you won't use it, consider installing a 100A or 125A panel to future-proof.

Comment: If you could handle 8 15A breakers, what actual load would you typically draw?

Comment: Another way of asking this is, what loads do you expect to power on a regular basis?

Comment: If you require 4 15 amp 120VAC circuts (and will fully load each circuit at the same time), a 30A 240V feed will run those. Or, a 60A 240V feed can run 8 of them. Only if your 15A circuits are 240V would you be limited to 4 off a 60A feed, and then only if you were actually fully loading all of those circuits. A 60A (or 50, 40, 30A) feed to a 100 amp panel might make a lot more sense, depending on current and possible future needs (and oddly the fact that 100A main breaker panels are sometimes a lot less expensive than smaller subpanels, depending on your supplier. They move in volume.

Comment: What loads are you trying to power here? Also, I take it the garage is a separate structure, and how many square feet is it?